# Where I can find the error log information in drupal7

Tags: drupal-7, watchdog

```
 watchdog($moduleName, $message, $variables = array($id), $severity = WATCHDOG_NOTICE, $link = NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In drupal all the information related to error will be logged into table name called as watchdog

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it through the ui: Navigate to /admin/reports/dblog